# How can I get the address of my local machine?

Tags: ssh, ip, remote, file-copy

I'm on a macbook running Lion. In `Terminal` I'm connected to my schools server with `ssh`. I navigated to a folder on the server and have a file I want to copy to my local machine, but I don't know what the IP address of my local machine is. How can I get it? I'm in the folder on the server, and I want to copy `read.txt` onto my local machine's hard drive. I've tried `scp ./read.txt [my computer name].local/newRead.txt` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to know your own host's IP address in order to copy files to it. Simply use `scp` to copy the file *from* the remote host:

```
$ scp user@rhost.com:path/to/read.txt ~/path/to/newRead.txt
```

If you want to copy *to* your local host from your remote host, get your own IP address with `ifconfig` and issue the following:

```
$ scp path/to/read.txt user@1.2.3.4:path/to/newRead.txt
```

where `1.2.3.4` is your local IP address. A convenient way to extract a host's IP address is using this function:

```
ipaddr() { (awk '{print $2}' <(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ')); }
```

where `eth0` is your network interface. Stick it in `~/.bash_profile` in order to run it as a regular command - `ipaddr`.

Comment: What if the command returns "ifconfig: interface eth0 does not exist"?

Comment: @kolistriva Try "en0".

Answer (score 10):

I just got the shortest way around this

```
$ who

root     pts/22       2016-12-28 13:22 (179.xx.xxx.xx)
```

If connected via ssh. This will display the user logged in plus the IP address

Comment: Or `echo $SSH_CLIENT` silghtly longer to type but almost no clutter to read.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding to the answer, an easy way to tell your address (ip/domain), is to ssh into a computer you can ssh into, exit and then ssh back into it again. Most times, you'll see a welcome message like:

```
"Last login at xx:xxpm from you.domain.com/ip.ad.dre.ss"
```

Comment: No need to log in and out, just type `last -ai`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ifconfig`. It should tell you your local IP address (on your network) for the various interfaces like WiFi and Ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

An easiest way to get IP address via SSH:

```
Command: ifconfig
```

Example:

```
stalinrajindian@ubuntuserver:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.3.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.30.3.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8b:9986  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:8b:99:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4876  bytes 1951791 (1.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 775  bytes 73783 (73.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 78  bytes 5618 (5.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78  bytes 5618 (5.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```